# I can't use "me and my family" may I use "with" instead?

Tags: grammar

May I say "please join me with my family for a reception immediately following the final selection" or is there a better way to phrase the statement?

Comment: I would replace "with" with "and" or "along with."

Comment: How about using "please join my family and me..." instead?

Comment: When you use with here it makes it seem as if you are joining you and your family together, as in physically putting you and your family together. "And" would be more appropriate, and placing "my family" before "me" would be more mannerly.

Answer (score 3):

Why can't you use *me and my family*? If it is only that you have been taught it is more polite to put yourself last, then you can say *my family and me*.

*With* there is probably understandable, but stilted and unnatural. Unless you are not a native English speaker, people are likely to try and find some extra meaning in your use of the unnatural word *with*.